# Using Express and Handlebars, how can I prefill or reload a select menu option from the database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

I have a user update form that I'm working on. The user can pick an option from a select menu, and that option gets saved to the db as a string.

```
<select name="morality" id="morality">
  <option value="">Choose down below!</option>
  <option value="Good"> Good</option>
  <option value="Neutral">Neutral</option>
  <option value="Evil">Evil</option>
</select>
```

When the user picks an option, I'm able to post to the database. When I reload the page, I'd like to get the chosen value and use it to add a selected attribute to the corresponding option. So if a person picks Neutral and saves it, I'd like to show...

```
<select name="morality" id="morality">
  <option value="">Choose down below!</option>
  <option value="Good"> Good</option>
  <option value="Neutral" selected >Neutral</option>
  <option value="Evil">Evil</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think when you refresh the page you have to call an API that fetches your selected option. 
if you didn't select any one option then you will see Choose down below! option. if you selected any option in db then you will get that and match with the option's value

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass value `morality` to view when rendering page :

```
router.get('/edit/:id', function(req, res) {
  Model.findOne({_id:req.params.id},function(err,data){
      if(!err && data){
         res.render('home',{morality:data.morality});
          // or you can pass whole data object to view 
          //res.render('home',{data:data});
          // inside view {{data.morality}}
      }
  });
});
```

and in view add condition like this :

```
<select name="morality" id="morality">
  <option value="" {{morality==''?'selected':''}}>Choose down below!</option>
  <option value="Good" {{morality=='Good'?'selected':''}}> Good</option>
  <option value="Neutral" {{morality=='Neutral'?'selected':''}}>Neutral</option>
  <option value="Evil"  {{morality=='Evil'?'selected':''}}>Evil</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I got an error for placing an equals sign in the views.